# Angular2 - Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two lists that I'm presenting in my `.html` file. I'm trying to make my code not repetitive so I decided to use `ngSwitch`, but I get an error while I do the next thing:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'People'">
      <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfPeople">
        <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#person of listOfPeople; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
          ID: {{bulk.person}} <p></p> Name: {{person.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Cars'">
      <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfCars">
        <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#car of listOfCars; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
          ID: {{car.id}} <p></p> Color: {{car.color}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

THIS IS THE ERROR IM GETTING FOR ECH LIST:

> (in promise): Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCase'
>   since it isn't a known native property ("
>
> ```
> <div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">
>     <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="'People'">
>       <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData"): AppCmp@42:9
> Property binding ngSwitchCase not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
>
>   <div [ngSwitch]="currentListView">
>     [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="'People'">
>       <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortabl"): AppCmp@42:4
> Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known native property ("
>       </div>
>     </div>
> ```

what is wrong here? and can I make it even more efficient?

thanks

Comment: Could you please show the error you are getting?

Comment: @eg16 aure added now, sorry i thought i did

Comment: From the error is clear that the way you are using the ngSwitchCase is wrong. Try to change them to [ngSwitchCase]="People"

Comment: but Places are also in the ngSwitchCase i just didnt added it to the question...

Comment: Okay, sorry. Can you please delete everything except divs with ngSwitchCases. Delete these <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOfPeople">
        <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#person of listOfPeople; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
          ID: {{bulk.person}} <p></p> Name: {{person.name}}
        </div>
      </div>

Answer (score 24):

If you use commons elements (ngSwitch, ngIf, ngFor, ...) of Angular2 you must import `CommonModule` in your app.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: BrowserModule already exports CommonModule, so you don't have to import CommonModule separately.

See here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/BrowserModule-class.html

Comment: My case was that I have imported wrongly a Module under declarations... and not under imports.

Answer (score 0):

With standalone components you'll certainly need both `NgSwitch` and `NgSwitchCase` imports.

CommonModule contains EVERYTHING so avoid that.

```
imports: [NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase]
```